# Selecting of data between a time period and calculating the difference of another parameter(time)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a DB with many tables and one of the table has fields:

id----number-----start-----end

Start corresponds to date and time of process: 2012-06-08 01:16:07

End correspond to end of the process         : 2012-06-08 01:39:47

I need to count all the processes that were in the previous 4 weeks, with a duration of above 10mins.....Just the no: processes is enough.

A php querying from the DB is required.Tried in a few ways but dint even get near. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'processes' FROM table1
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) > 10
AND start BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbtable
WHERE start > TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -4, CURDATE())
      AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) > 10;
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) if looking for # of processes as above.

Comment: I just added to count the no: rows after selecting the DB.